# Pass parameters to NUnit test

Tags: c#, selenium, jenkins, nunit, automated-tests

I'm calling nunit test from Jenkins and I need to be able to specify just one URL address as parameter which I can use inside test. Is there possibility to do that?
For example I'm calling "Execute Windows batch command" in Jenkins like that:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.4\bin\nunit-console.exe" "D:\selenium\SeleniumTest.dll" /run:SeleniumTest.Test.MyTest
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I currently know of, there is no solution to provide just that what you describe that you want. Best option is to use NUnit project files, modify settings there and pass the solution file to the runner.

On the other hand, you could try to use the `Environment` variable.

Use set from the command-line. Then read the value using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()` and use that within your testmethod.